# What is a way to reword "He dashed and arrived in front of her"

Tags: word-choice

> He dashed and arrived in front of her.

Is there a way to combine the "dashed and arrived" into one word, or change the sentence so that only dashed is used but retains the original meaning?

This:

> He dashed in front of her.

That, to me, gives off a feeling that while being in front of her, he is dashing *past* her but not to the location that is "in front of her".

And this:

> He dashed to the location that was in front of her.

That sounds too wordy to me, and it would be prefered if it was kept short with minimal words. I am aiming for something like example #2 (the shortest one), but that just simply doesn't sound too right.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. *He darted in front of her.* This only applies if he only had to travel a short distance to arrive in front of her, but if he had to run 100 feet, you are talking about to separate events, and trying to combine them probably does not make much sense anyway. You might also say: *He dashed in front of her.*

Comment: Would "He dashed in front of her" have the meaning that he dashed and arrived in front of her though? "He dashed in front of her" sounds somewhat vague (but might just be me) as he could either be dashing towards her and stopping when he is in front of her, but in a way, he could also be dashing past in front of her (perpendicularly)

Comment: He certainly could be. Presumably the context makes his previous position clear. One of the things peculiar to language (relative to physics) is its lack of precision in specifying the velocity of moving bodies.

Answer (score 0):

First, in AmE, you'd do better to use "sprint" rather than "dash". It's true that we have the "100-yard dash" and not the "100-yard sprint", but "sprint" only has one meaning, while "dash" has several, including to destroy as in the phrase "dashed his hopes", and the verb form is not widely used.

Second, to say that "he sprinted ahead of her" does not clearly suggest that he did so to occupy a specific place and prevent her from reaching it is correct, but ordinarily the possibility would be established before the sentence is encountered.